# Akka, wrap JacksonJsonSerializer

Tags: scala, serialization, akka

I would like to add some information to the manifest and JSON representation of my serialized objects. However, I do not want to handle all the subtle cases and the migrations that are already well handled by `akka.serialization.jackson.JacksonJsonSerializer`.

That's why I would like to get a reference to the `JacksonJsonSerializer` from my own serializer so that I can easily decorate the outputs without having to reimplement everything.

I tried to retrieve the serializer from his FQN:

```
  private lazy val jackson = {
    SerializationExtension(system)
      .serializerOf("akka.serialization.jackson.JacksonJsonSerializer")
      .map(_.asInstanceOf[SerializerWithStringManifest])
      .get
  }
```

However, this raise the exception:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: akka.serialization.jackson.JacksonJsonSerializer.()

This exception is raised because `JacksonJsonSerializer` constructor expect the extended actor system and a String which should be the binding name. And, the method `akka.serialization.Serialization#serializerOf` (that should use that constructor) rethrow the exception when the binding name is empty. Unfortunately, I cannot pass the binding name.

So, my question is:

Can I get an existing serializer from the `ExtendedSystem` or any other means available to an `akka.serialization.Serializer`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can access instance of `JacksonJsonSerializer` in the following ways:

1. It's possible to use [Serialization.serializerFor](https://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/2.8/akka/serialization/Serialization.html#serializerFor(java.lang.Class)) passing binded class as a parameter. Akka will lookup for corresponding serializer and return `JacksonJsonSerializer` instance if configured so.
2. [Construct](https://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/2.6.0/akka/serialization/jackson/JacksonJsonSerializer.html#%3Cinit%3E(akka.actor.ExtendedActorSystem,java.lang.String)) it by yourself with `ExtendedSystem` and binding name. But be aware, that corresponding serializer id should be defined for the given binding name in `akka.actor.serialization-identifiers.{bindingName}` of your configuration.
3. [not recemmended] Use reflection mechanisms to access private method `serializerOf` of `Serialization` class where binding name can be defined:

   ```
   var serialization = SerializationExtension.get(system);
   var method = Serialization.class.getDeclaredMethod("serializerOf", String.class, String.class);
   method.trySetAccessible();
   var serializerTry = (Try<Serializer>) method.invoke(
       serialization,
       "jackson-json",
       "akka.serialization.jackson.JacksonJsonSerializer"
   );
   assert serializerTry.isSuccess();
   var serializer = serializerTry.get();
   ```